# How to render text in bold in next-share NPM on email content component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

I'm using the [next-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-share) NPM EmailShareButton component. In the body im trying to bold the text with a  but its rendering object Object instead on the email.. How can i highlight a text in bold in const when it render out in the email service.. this is my code

```
const body =
    <bold> + job.title + </bold> + ' \n\n' +
    job?.description.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').replace('&nbsp;', ' ').slice(0, 100) + '... \n\n';
```

It renders as object instead when i compile...

```
[object Object] 
        
Our client is a leading Moving Company with an office in Pittsburgh, PA and we are assisting them in...
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the full code where this is code is expected to run. Also, if you're attempted to embed the `body` variable inside JSX, then it won't work. Something like this would work: `const body =
    <strong> + {job.title} + </strong> + ' \n\n' + ...`. Also, use the `<strong>` to highlight bold text instead of `<bold>` tag.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear enough. i'm actually using the next-share NPM email component.. under the email body, it outputs [object Object].. i've attached the screenshot for your reference.. please help if you've any idea..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const body =
    '<bold>'+ job.title + '</bold> '+ ' \n\n' +
    job?.description.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').replace('&nbsp;', ' ').slice(0, 100) + '... \n\n';
```

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear enough.. im actually using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-share for the email service. under the body, i want to display the following text with a bold text.. but its rendering object instead with my code.. i tried to use your method but it does not work as well